# Как парсить страницу сайта по https?

Tags: php, ubuntu, парсер, ssl, https

Как парсить сайты через https? Пытаюсь подключиться к веб-интерфейсу elastix-asterisk. Использую код:

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // times out after 4s
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return into a variable
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://192.168.0.18/");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 GTB6");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    print_r($data);
```

Причем часть сайтов парсится например яндекс, твитер и хабр. А здесь возникает ошибка:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\parser.loc\simple_html_dom.php on line 75
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\parser.loc\simple_html_dom.php on line 75
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://192.168.0.18/): failed to open
>   stream: operation failed in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\parser.loc\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

В файрфоксе пишет при подключении:

> 192.168.0.18 использует недействительный сертификат безопасности. К сертификату нет доверия, так как он является самоподписанным.
>   Сертификат действителен только для localhost.localdomain Код ошибки:
>   SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Тогда я взял сертификат и добавил его к остальным, но опять же появляется ошибка:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Peer certificate
>   CN=`localhost.localdomain' did not match expected CN=`192.168.0.18' in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\parser.loc\simple_html_dom.php on line 75
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\parser.loc\simple_html_dom.php on line 75
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://192.168.0.18/): failed to open
>   stream: operation failed in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\parser.loc\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

То есть сертификат выпущен для **localhost.localdomainn**. Как быть дальше?
С эластиксом получилось, а сдругим сайтом не выходит пишет при заходе на сайт:

> [image: ошибка в firefox]

как парсить такие сайты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Отключите проверку сертификатов.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: да, действительно, получилось с эластиксом, с другим сайтом не получается так.

Comment: Значит с другим сайтом проблема глубже, чем неверный сертификат. Например он вовсе не доступен по https

Comment: с другим сайтом разобрался через iframe и javascript) спасибо)

Comment: С другим сайтом и правда было сложнее, нужно было добавить поддержку ГОСТ в SSL, по этой инструкции сделал http://zubuntu.ru/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8-gost-%D0%B2-ssl/